# How to load this script tag dynamically in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a website written in ReactJS. I need to load the following script at a certain point on the site, not at launch:

```
<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript">(function($,document) ... bla bla bla )</script>
```

I do not want to lose the attributes given to the script. How do I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: You should use `useEffect` hook for loading it dynamically

Comment: Can you demonstrate, as I dont know what you are referring to

Comment: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-load-a-dynamic-script-in-react-2940d30998dd

Comment: I have tried this. The script itself is very long. When I just paste it in the index.html file, it does not load with errors. When I use this method, I get 'Parsing Errors'. What could be the reason for this ?